# SwiftUI : Using NavigationView leads to image and text gone

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationview

What I'm gonna do is..
If I click a menu, then it goes to a detailed menu-description page.

[image]

but It seems to something wrong. the code is the below.

[contentview.swift]

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            List{
                Text("Menu")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                ForEach(menu){ section in
                    Section(header: Text(section.name) , content: {
                        ForEach(section.items.indices)
                        {
                            index in ItemRow(item:section.items[index])
                        }
                    })
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
```

[ItemRow.swift]

```
struct ItemRow: View {
    let item: MenuItem
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //NavigationView{
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetail(item:item)) {
                    HStack{
                        Image(item.thumbnailImage)
                        VStack(alignment:.leading){
                            Text(item.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("$\(item.price)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

I intentionally commented out the 'NaviagationView'.
because If I activate that comment relating to NavigationNiew..

[image]

See? It seems weird. I still wonder what i did wrong..
Before adding the navigation code, the menu was shown on the Preview well.
Could you give me some tips?

===============================
My Problem has been solved!

[ContentView.swift]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            ItemList()
    }
}
```

[ItemList.swift]

```
struct ItemList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack(alignment:.leading){
                List{
                    Text("Menu")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    ForEach(menu){ section in
                        Section(header: Text(section.name) , content: {
                            ForEach(section.items.indices)
                            {
                                index in
                                //ItemRow(item:section.items[index])
                                
                                NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetail(item:section.items[index])) {
                                    HStack{
                                        Image(section.items[index].thumbnailImage)
                                        VStack(alignment:.leading){
                                            Text(section.items[index].name)
                                                .font(.headline)
                                            Text("$\(section.items[index].price)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely delete the `NavigationView` inside `ItemRow`. That's where the back buttons are coming from.

Comment: Try putting `NavigationLink` outside `ItemRow` instead of inside

Comment: Thank you.. I've tried so hard..I'll upload what I've done soon..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is usually only one `NavigationView` in an app. It is usually the outer most `View`.

In this case put it above the `VStack` in the `ContentView`.

One of the most common exceptions are sheets.